# pass an ID to next page after clicking a link in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a list of places that I am printing list of places, and the idea is when the user clicks on the place it takes the user to another page where the details of the place can be viewed. How can I achieve this?

HTML:Page1

```
<li ng-repeat="place in places.places">
    <a href="#/uncatdetails" ng-click="showplace(place.placeID)">{{place.name}}</a>
</li>
```

Page2:

```
<table ng-controller="UncatCtrl">
    <tr>
        <td>Name: </td><td>{{place.place.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>placeID: </td><td ng-model="PlaceID">{{place.place.placeID}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Angular:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/uncatdetails', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/uncatpost.html',
    controller: 'UnCatPostCtrl'
    })
}])
.controller('UnCatPostCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {})

.controller('UncatCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

$http.get('http://94.125.132.253:8000/getuncategorisedplaces').success(function (data, status, headers) {

    $scope.places = data;
    console.log(data);
    $scope.message = 'Uncategorised places';
})

$scope.showplace = function(placeID) {
  $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://94.125.132.253:8000/getitemdata?ID=' + placeID}).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.place = data;               //set view model
          console.log(data);
          console.log(placeID);
           $scope.view = 'templates/detail.html';

      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.place = data || "Request failed";
          $scope.status = status;
          $scope.view = 'templates/detail.html';
      });
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it

```
.when('/uncatdetails/:id', {templateUrl: 'ftemplates/uncatpost.html',
controller: 'UnCatPostCtrl'})
```

in your HTML

```
ng-href="uncatdetails/{{place.placeID}}"
```

in your controller, add this inject $routeParams

```
$scope.id = $routeParams.id;
```

Comment: This passes the ID but does not print the data requested

Comment: so you call your function $scope.showplace and get data

Comment: yes I did that and in my URI I needed to add  URI/ + $scope.id. Its working now, thanks